# Is there a way to create multiple things in IOT and map them to a DynamoDB table with things and their details through Java Springboot?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

In AWS IOT-core I want to create multiple things, put them in a group and give each thing details, like manufacture name, id, etc (maybe through Attribute key and value) and get them to enter a dynamoDB table through java springboot. Is there any java function that can make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IoT Core provides Java SDK for these purpose.

You may refer my GitHub project where I have used IoT SDK to create thing and assign certificate and policy - https://github.com/alokkusingh/iot-core

[AWS API Spec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_Operations_AWS_IoT.html)

Answer (score 0):

AWS IoT has concept called bulk registration and fleet provisioning which can help you. Technically, you need to define provisioning templates which is a JSON document and have to use it.

Regarding, DynamoDB mapping, I suppose (need to check more on it) you can use provisioning hooks for it.

More Details on bulk registration - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/provision-template.html

Provisioning templates - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/provision-template.html